# complex ActiveRecord query - search within hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Three tables, for a distributed library system:

```
Class Book       # model: id, name, auhtor
  has_many :book_belongs
  has_many :owners, through: :book_belongs, source: :user

Class User       # model: id, name, email, facebook_uid, facebook_friends
  has_many :book_belongs
  has_many :ownedbooks, through: :book_belongs, source: :book

Class BookBelong # model: user_id, book_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
```

@user.facebookfriends is a (serialized) hash that contain the facebook_id and facebook_name of a user facebook friends

I am having trouble in designing a ruby/rails activerecord query that:

- returns the books that are owned by facebook friends.

In "english" the query should look at book owners facebook_id and match to the user facebook_friends hash.

- Is there a better way to design the tables/data model to make this simpler and less expensive to compute?

Answer (score 0):

Ok - solved, using

```
BookBelong.joins(:book).joins(:user).where('users.uid' => current_user.friends.keys)
```

and getting the actual Books at the view using a simple

```
  <% @friends_books.each do |book| %>
    <td><%= book.book.name %></td>
```

Doesn't seem to be super-efficient, though.